# How to indicate this formula with nabla operator?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, linear-algebra

I found this in the fluid mechanics:
$F(u)=\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial y}\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial z}\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u_x}{\partial y}\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u_y}{\partial z}\frac{\partial u_z}{\partial y}$

where $u=[u_{x},u_{y},u_{z}]$ is a vector field, I just wounder that how to indicate $F(u)$ with nabla operator $\nabla$?

Comment: This is more of a math question.

Comment: It looks like the sign is swapped when swapping component vs. partial derivative in the cross terms. I think you need some sum that permutes $u$ if you want to keep $\nabla$.

Comment: Are you sure you typed this correctly?

Comment: Actually all the minus terms' factors are mixed partials, so what I wrote might not be sufficient...

Comment: It overlaps the sum of divergence squared plus curl squared, but.....

Answer (score 1):

Writing this expression in Einstein summation notation:

$$F(u)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_j} - \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_i}$$

Note that the outer product of $u$ and $\nabla$ is precisely $(\nabla\otimes u)_{ij}=\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$, and so:

$$F(u)=\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\otimes u)_{ii}(\nabla\otimes u)_{jj} - \frac{1}{2}(\nabla\otimes u)_{ij}(\nabla\otimes u)_{ji}$$

Now note that, summing over repeated indices, $A_{ii}=\mathrm{tr}(A)$ for a matrix $A$, and $(A^2)_{ij}=A_{ik}A_{kj}$. Using these two facts, we have immediately that

$$F(u)=\frac{1}{2}(\mathrm{tr}(\nabla\otimes u))^2-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}((\nabla\otimes u)^2)$$

This is a nicely symmetric result. However, there is another helpful identity: the trace of the outer product is equivalent to the inner product. As such, we can write the first term as a divergence. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a simple expression for the second term, so this is an alternative (not necessarily simpler or better) formulation:

$$F(u)=\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\cdot u)^2-\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{tr}((\nabla\otimes u)^2)$$

Comment: Sincerely appreciate for your answer! however, i have try the formula in 3d and found that $(tr(∇⊗u))^2−tr((∇⊗u)^2)=2u_{x,x}u_{y,y}+2u_{x,x}u_{z,z}+2u_{y,y}u_{z,z}-u_{x,y}u_{y,x}-u_{x,z}u_{z,y}-u_{y,z}u_{z,y}$ and feel a bit confused.

Comment: @Nothingts Sorry, I forgot about a global factor of 1/2 (the initial expression exactly double-counts every term). I encourage you to check your own calculations again, as this seems to yield the correct expression when I implement it on Mathematica.